# Calling method from parent class in PHP?

Tags: php, class-visibility

I can't seem to figure out a way to call a method called `insertValue()`;

My bootstrap takes the url and splits it into pieces so www.URL.com/register/register becomes

```
url[0]=register;  
url[1] = register;  
$controller = new url[0];  
$controller->loadModel();  
if islet($url[1])  
    $controller->{url[1]};  

class Controller { 
    public $model; 
    function __construct() { 
        $this->view = new View(); //(irrelevant) 
    } 
    public function loadModel($name) { 
        ... 
        $this->model = new $modelName; 
    }
}
```

The model class is as follows

```
class Model { 
    public $database;
    function__construct() { 
        $this->database = new Database();
    } 
}
```

So the database class is as follows

```
class Database { 
    insertValue(){ 
    ... 
    }
}
```

Now, I have a bootstrap which creates a register class that extends controller as follows:

```
class Register extends Controller {
    function__construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public static function register (){
        HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL THE INSERT VALUE FUNCTION FROM DATABASE CLASS
    }
}
```

The bootstrap also creates my model class by saying `Register->loadModel();` which simply looks like this:

```
class registerModel extends Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
   }
```

I can't at all figure out how to call the insertValue function. I tried `$this->model->database->insertValue();` but that didn't work.

P.S. I notice that when I call this function, that the code beneath it does not get called, but no error message is given.

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to edit codes in post properly.

Comment: Try `$this->model->database->insertValue()`, assuming that `loadModel()` has been called already.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors.

Comment: Have you even heard about dependency injection ?

Comment: Netbeans tells me of no syntax errors. What are they?

Comment: No, I haven't but I'll look it up. Will it help me in this case?

Comment: @AlexHeuman: `$public model;`, on the second line of your first snippet. That's a syntax error.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Sorry, typed it wrong here. It's not like that in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `$this->model->database->insertValue()` ? after calling `loadModel()` inside your controller construct.

Comment: Yes, that's what i've been trying and it doesn't seam to work.

Comment: The model automatically get's loaded in my bootstrap. $controller = new $url[0];
        $controller->loadModel($url[0]);

        if (isset($url[2])) {
            $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
        } else {
            @$controller->{$url[1]}();
        }